# Windows phone 8 images are wider than the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I've been trying to solve an issue that only happens on Windows phone 8. They use as a browser IE10. In many responsive design projects I've checked that all the mobile phones work correctly except this mobile phone and it's browser.

**The issue**

The images are bigger than the viewport itself making the image overflow by the right side of the screen. This overflow creates an uncomfortable scrolling in it's x-axis.

**Possible solutions which did not work for me**

[Matt stow solution](http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html#the-fix)

[CSS tricks solution](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/fix-ie-10-on-windows-phone-8-viewport/)

I'm testing with a nokia lumia 925 and a nokia lumia 520. If I apply this solution they both have different layouts. Especially the nkia 925 as it has a big resolution the media queries act strangely, as it was a tablet.

Does anybody have a clear and working solution which does not break other devices layout?

Comment: could it be something with IE's default css? Maybe there is some padding or margin in there. Are you using a Reset.css file?  I'm a bit new to this, but I've also used css3-mediaqueries.js for some IE browsers. Just an idea :)

Comment: @deebs This project already works on all browsers so it is responsive. I used media queries and it works fine, it seems an issue with the viewport but I did not find a solid solution for the images being bigger than the viewport... So.. let's see if somebody has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday i had the same Problem and yes i visited the same pages like you.
I just added an

```
.im_the_parent_class_of_the_image {
   overflow:hidden
 }
```

to the parent class/element of the image and it still works fine for me and no other browser was affected.

Comment: This would solve the issue regarding the overflow of the whole body. But then the image will be cut. This helps but does not solve the issue that windows phone 8 makes the images bigger than the 100% of the container. Do you have more input?